# Memory leak because of HibernateSessionImpl in Spring batch

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

I've written a spring batch application that uses JPA+ Hibernate model for read-write operations.

I'm getting OutOfmemory error due to hibernateSessionImpl object.

I'm using JPA entity manager factory: `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`

as a singleton bean configured in spring.xml

Error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.util.HashMap.createHashedEntry(HashMap.java:650)
at java.util.HashMap.putImpl(HashMap.java:629)
at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:605)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.postFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:366)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:960)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
at $Proxy43.flush(Unknown Source)
at com.bunge.portal.core.dao.jpa.RssGenericDaoJpaImpl.create(RssGenericDaoJpaImpl.java:200)
at com.bunge.portal.rss.repository.RssFeedContentCacheRepositoryImpl.create(RssFeedContentCacheRepositoryImpl.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy44.create(Unknown Source)
at com.bunge.portal.rss.service.RssFeedServiceImpl.createRssFeedContentCache(RssFeedServiceImpl.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
15:22:08,023 ERROR AbstractStep:212 - Encountered an error executing the step
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step
at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:110)
at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:135)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:61)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:144)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:124)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:281)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:120)
at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:48)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:114)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:349)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574)
```

Comment: And add the complete stacktrace.

Comment: I'm getting error while  calling the create() method.

Comment: It do not looks like a memory leak. Your application only neads more memory.

Comment: How did you find out? Can you explain?

Comment: the stacktrace tells me, that while trying to flush the changes to the database, hibernate does not have enough memory to do so, details which might help to find the cause for this, how do you run the batch?, how many items are in one flush (commit-rate)? how complex are the items (parent-children-children...)? how complex is the mapping definition?

Comment: I'm running the batch on a shared JVM with portal server, i'm flushing all the objects at once to DB. There is a VO which has one to many relationship.. Hope this helps to suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was we were fetching 8000 records in one of the queries and using only first record. The batch was running successfully as the number of records in table were less, but as time passed the total records were too many and it was overflowing the heap memory,i changed the query to fetch only one record the latest one and it works fine....

Thanks for you help everyone..!!